# Push Notifications on Android and iOS without third parties such as Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

I have developed an app, using `Ionic Framework with React`, running on top of `Capacitor`. Now I have to implement **Push Notifications** on `Android` and `iOS`, but I'm requested **to not use** third parties such as Firebase. It's not my decision!

Example: A part of my app is showing Sale History of the user. I would like to have a push notification, every time a new sale is added.

How do I show Sale History in the app?

```
useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true;
    const options = {
      url: baseURL + "/sale-history",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Token: token,
      },
    };
    
    Http.request({ ...options, method: "GET" })
      .then((response) => {
        if (mounted.current) {
          setSaleEntries(response.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error in sale history");
      });
    return () => {
      mounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

Do you have any idea how can I implement Push notifications without third parties, for example in a static way?

Comment: You can't. You have to have a Push notification service from one of the providers. either use: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm,  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/pushape-push, 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/wonderpush,
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal 
These are some services providers with ionic plugins.

Comment: Firebase is not a third party for android, it belongs to google and it’s the official way of sending push notifications.

Comment: @jcesarmobile, what about creating a service for sending just notifications, not exactly push notifications? Is this possible in Ionic? https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Comment: @jcesarmobile,
Maybe this one : `@capacitor/local-notifications`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@capacitor/push-notifications](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications) which provides access to the native push notification API on both the platforms. However, the library uses Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK as a dependency on Android, it cannot be avoided.

For iOS, assuming your backend is handling communication with Apple's APNS servers, you  can grab the APNS token using `addListener(eventName: 'registration', listenerFunc: (token: Token) => void) => Promise<PluginListenerHandle> & PluginListenerHandle`